# Global array causes segfault when declared normally but not as pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, global

I am using a global array (I know they are evil). This is not so much a problem, but I don't know why it works one way and not the other, as they should be the same. (that and otherwise I need to deallocate memory after in the currently working way).

Anyway, I have this Snake class. I want to make, this being the global array:

```
Snake snakes[8];
```

I have several (or will anyway) several classes and function that interact with this. The problem in question occurs with a setter function in the Snake class. It compiles fine, but segfaults. It turned out, this was a null pointer (0x0). Not sure why. The stack trace in this case came from a function call from another file, which includes the snake header and has this:

```
extern Snake * snakes;
```

An array's name is a pointer, so I figured this should work. Oddly enough, it does not. I have no idea why.

But, when I change the declaration from what it was to:

```
Snake * snakes;
```

And later allocate it like so:

```
snakes = new Snake [8];
```

It works! But, then I need to deallocate something else I didn't want to, when the number of snakes is constant. (8).

Also, the function call in question accesses the 0th element, where there were 8 elements each time.

Any idea what causes this?

On a side note, are global variables still evil when in a named namespace? (not anonymous). I ask because I am trying to get into the OO habit and logically structure things, which I am certain will pay off compared to my last endeavors, the encapsulation, organization, etc, all make sense. (and maybe in a few years, compile time). Still, having to include a scoped variable in a function call for setting seems... bad. Is that proper or is there a better way? (then global, namespace or otherwise)

EDIT: The error is a segfault, at the line of the member function.

Snake member function:

```
void setValue(Some value here...) {this-> value = input)
```

The call from the file that externed the global array:

```
snakes[0].setValue(some value here...)
```

Comment: you ought to include the crashing code, otherwise one can only guess what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array's name is **not** a pointer. In most contexts it **decays** into a pointer, but when it doesn't, it doesn't. So if you have:

```
Snake snakes[8];
```

in one source file and

```
extern Snake *snakes; // don't do this
```

in another, you'll get all kinds of mysterious problems, including crashes. For an array, the extern declaration **must** declare an array:

```
extern Snake snakes[];
```

Incidentally, I know this because I had **exactly** the same problem many years ago, and that's when I figured out how to do this.

Comment: Oh. But isn't accessing indexes always using pointer arithmetic?   Also, is this only for extern? For example, if I am passing paremeters, that is always pointers, right? (otherwise it would pass what is at that index, I think). Finally, let's say I have a 2D array. Do I use it like extern SOMETHING[][]?

Comment: @user190929, To the first point, yes (at least with arguments of a pointer and integer), but the array decays to a pointer in order to make it work.

Comment: The first definition of `snakes` says that it's an array; the first `extern` declaration says that it's a pointer. They're different types. When you pass an array to a function, its name decays into a pointer to the first element, so you're effectively passing a pointer. A 2D array is trickier: you can only omit the rightmost dimension. When you pass a 2D array to a function, the name decays into a pointer, so you can pass `int a[2][3]` to a function that takes `int *ptr[2]`.

Comment: I guess tuturials mostly dumb it down, then. (mine, at least). Although     mabye that partially explains segfaults... I will look into it. Do you know anything on the second point?